# Creating a Set data type

Tags: haskell, types

So I need to create a Set data type in Haskell.

So, for the first part of my question I need to define the

```
type Set a = ...
```

I have it set as

```
type Set a = Set [a]
```

because Set would just be a list of alphas, right?
Or, would the correct way to do it be

```
type Set a = ([a])
```

Then, for the next part I need to implement a function

```
setSuchThat :: (a -> Bool) -> (Set a)
```

The function takes a characteristic function f and returns a set such that the value x(of appropriate type) is in the set only when f(x) is True. So an example of it in use would be,

```
setSuchThat (\x -> x == "coke")
```

So my question is now, is in that function I would essentially need to evaluate that function to get "coke" and then add it to my Set. I guess I just don't understand how, in this function, I would go about doing this.

Comment: Look up the source code for `filter`. You will find that `setSuchThat = filter`.

Comment: That would be impossible. There's an infinite number of possible strings. How would the program know when it has all of the values which will return `True`? A more realistic solution would be to use `filter`.

Comment: If the only function you have to implement is `setSuchThat`, then let me suggest `type Set a = a -> Bool`. You should then find `setSuchThat` trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I am not entirely sure still what to do, but yes, there are more functions that need to be implemented such as unions and intersection.

Comment: It would be either `type Set a = [a]` or `data Set a = Set [a]`. The latter would be necessary if you want `Set` to be a distinct data structure, rather than just another name for a list. You would want that, since you don't really want `Set [1] ++ Set [1]` to be `Set [1,1]`, or even compile.

Answer (score 4):

Following Daniel Wagner’s suggestion, you can define a set as a *predicate* that indicates whether an element is in the set:

```
type Set a = a -> Bool
```

For good measure, I’ll use a `newtype` to make it clearer where we’re using sets:

```
newtype Set a = Set { contains :: a -> Bool }
```

Then `setSuchThat` just wraps a predicate in `Set`:

```
setSuchThat :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a
setSuchThat = Set
```

You can test for membership in a set using the `contains` function:

```
> setSuchThat (== "coke") `contains` "coke"
True

> setSuchThat (== "coke") `contains` "pepsi"
False
```

So an empty set is just `setSuchThat (const False)`—for any given element, it always answers the question “Does the set contain this element?” with “No”.

Then you can implement functions such as `insert` to extend the set with a new element by *composing* the existing `contains` function with a new function:

```
insert :: (Eq a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x s = Set $ \ x' -> x == x' || s `contains` x'

> insert "pepsi" (setSuchThat (== "coke")) `contains` "pepsi"
True
```

Other functions like `union` are easy:

```
union :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union s1 s2 = Set $ \ x -> s1 `contains` x || s2 `contains` x

> let sodas = setSuchThat (== "coke") `union` setSuchThat (== "pepsi")

> sodas `contains` "coke"
True

> sodas `contains` "pepsi"
True

> sodas `contains` "water"
False
```

As an exercise, try implementing other set functions like `delete`, `intersect`, and `difference`.

One drawback to this approach is that every lookup is linear—O(n)—in the number of elements that have been inserted or deleted. In addition, you can’t simply enumerate all the elements of the set to convert it to a list—you can only enumerate *values* and *test* whether each one is an element. However, one *advantage* is that this lets you easily represent infinite sets; for example, `setSuchThat (> 0)` contains all non-negative numbers.

That’s why the standard `Data.Set` type uses a tree-based data structure instead of functions, representing elements as their actual values. With that approach, values can be deleted without increasing the size of the set, and since it uses `Ord` instead of `Eq`, it achieves more efficient logarithmic—O(log n)—lookups and insertions.

Answer (score 1):

To build on what [Jon Purdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246886/jon-purdy) has laid out:

You need to think of the `Set a = a -> Bool` as a restriction that you have to work with.  When you look at `setSuchThat :: (a -> Bool) -> (Set a)` you can read it to be the same as `setSuchThat :: (Set a) -> (Set a)` or `setSuchThat :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)`.  `setSuchThat` is kind of like a mcguffin, it's just there to make using the functions more clear - it is unnecessary.

Everything you are doing is taking function `f` and applying it to variable `x`.  The entire point of `setSuchThat` is to be passed `f` and `x` and return  only `f x`.